# Sort the obj in array By React useEffect method

Tags: reactjs, sorting, use-effect, arrayobject

I only paste a part of my React Code here, I have an array in my State, it can be updated and added the new array from browser.

My question is I want that array can be sorted from smallest to greatest on the time values and output to console.log, when the array was updated, how can I make it sort correctly by useEffect method?

The array structure is like the following code, the other part just control the UI updating I haven’t post there because those parts do not affect that sorting function.

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([ 
{time: 3, msg:”there is the first msg”},
{time: 6, msg:”2nd msg”},
{time:11, msg:”do you have any question?”}
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) which will sort the array only when `rows` changes

```
const [rows, setRows] = React.useState([
    { time: 3, msg: 'there is the first msg' },
    { time: 6, msg: '2nd msg' },
    { time: 11, msg: 'do you have any question?' },
]);

const sorted = React.useMemo(() => rows.slice().sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time), [rows]);

console.log(sorted);
```

but in most cases react is very fast and you can sort the array every render and don't worry about performance

```
const sorted = rows.slice().sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` and add `rows` in its dependencies array, so it'll watch whenever rows is updated.
There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Create a new state variable to save the sorted array

```js
const [sortedRows, setSortedRows] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
  const _sortedRows = [...rows].sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time); // as sort mutates the array, thats why created new array through spread operator
  setSortedRows(_sortedRows);
}, [rows])
```

2. Use `useMemo` hook:

```js
const sortedRows = React.useMemo(() => [...rows].sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time), [rows])
```

Comment: get infinite rendering, because `setRows` set new array `rows`, `useEffect` called because `rows` changed :)